# when using the button "edit" the already registered email-adresses disappear except for the primary email-adress

Tags: contacts, error

when using the button "edit" the already registered email-adresses disappear except for the primary email-adress[image]

--> answer to Erik Hommel:

We are currently using 5.15.1

screen shot before we have edited the information

[image]

and now after editing.

[image]

Comment: Bernard, it will help us to help you if you provide us the version of CiviCRM you are using and some more information about the exact flow of what you are doing and what results you are expecting.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot where the email is not shown ? Also, do you have any custom extension installed on your site?

Comment: I have added some more information in the post.

Comment: Can you replicate on eg dmaster.demo.civicrm.org - if not it may be something in your theme or other plugins affecting you

Comment: We have changed recently to the new theme. I will rollback this on a test instance and will see if this happens also in the old theme.

Comment: We have found the problem. It was indeed due to a custom extension that didn't work properly anymore after the last (?) update.  Case closed